# Show Item Weight - Shopping Cart - Magento 2

Tags: magento2

How can I show the weight for each item in the shopping cart? Is there any option to enable for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this code `$_item->getProduct()->getWeight();` at `default.phtml(app\design\frontent\Vendor\ThemeName\Magento_Checkout\templates\cart\item)`

Comment: Worked man. Thanks. Do you know where I can edit the table headings for the shopping cart? I added the weight as a column in that file and now I need to add to the heading as well.

Comment: In magento 1.9.2.3 where i can add this code?